# CSS transition is only working in FireFox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I made a basic website with an animation and a transition.
If you click 1 of the 5 columns / bars then the one clicked goes animated to fullscreen like it's supposed to.
If you click on the fullscreen version to close it then the text field collapses with jquery. This works on all browsers. After that it should transition to the bar/column again but it only does that in firefox. In the other browsers I tested (chrome / safari) it goes instant to that position.

The way I have it now is if you are fullscreen (focus) and click then it collapses the text and has a callback where it adds a class transition:

```
$story.slideUp("fast", function() {  
       $item.addClass("transition"); 
       $item.removeClass("focus");
});
```

The css class:

```
.transition {
     -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.320, 0.715, 0.470, 0.830);
     -moz-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.320, 0.715, 0.470, 0.830);
     -o-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.320, 0.715, 0.470, 0.830);
     -ms-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.320, 0.715, 0.470, 0.830);
     transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.320, 0.715, 0.470, 0.830);
}
```

Here I have the whole thing in a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/clankill3r/actrsjo2/

I tried to debug it for quite a while but nothing seems to work.
I hope I miss something really stupid.
Hope someone can help.

Comment: Transitions are working fine for me. However, there seems to be a severe case of vendor-itis in your code: there is no such thing as `-o-filter`, `-ms-filter` and `-moz-filter`, as well as `-ms-transition`.

Comment: @Terry What? [That's just not true](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/08/microsoft-css-vendor-extensions.aspx). And things like `-ms-transition` are required for IE9 support.